# Increase Decrease Values from One Sheet to Another Sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have one sheet named Sheet3 and another are Sheet4. Sheet3: Column A Header is Product type, and Column B is their Quantity, Sheet4 has same column Header. Product Type and Quantity. But when I Run Below Macro in Sheet3, Sometime they add values correctly to
Sheet4 and sometime they doesn't work properly.

```
    Sub Increase_Value()

    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Cells.Find(What:=Sheet4.Range("A2").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("E10").Select

        Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Cells.Find(What:=Sheet4.Range("A3").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("E10").Select
    
        Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Cells.Find(What:=Sheet4.Range("A4").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Range("E10").Select
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("A2:B4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

For Example: `If Sheet3 Range A3 = **Coca Cola**, And B3 = **20**`, And When I rum the macro `Increase_Value()`, The VBA should find the value **Coca Cola** in Sheet4 Column A and if value found in row 10 (A10) then add value 20 from sheet3 Range B3 to sheet4 Range B10.
If B10 is 47 then after running the macro it should be 67.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to do something that a vlookup could solve easily? You can do vlookups in VBA as well

Below is the exact formula -
'''Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, range_lookup)'''

You can find more information on this here:
https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-vlookup/

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks For Quick Reply Mr. NonieTech. Vlookup is for getting values from a table, but I want Increase and decrease value. like Stock Add, Stock Subtract.